# Align top line of two tables side by side and their caption

Tags: tables

I am trying to align these two tables that unfortunately are uneven on the top *hline*.
The results are upsetting. I'm using minipage to have the two tables side by side. If you have any idea how to make this look better, please share :)

P.S. I know there is already a very similar question asked by @warem but it seems not to work for me.

here is the code:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   \textbf{SKU}&\textbf{Price}&\textbf{Supplier}\\\hline
        quinoa 90g &   € 0.21& Alfa BV\\\hline
        quinoa 180g&   € 0.30& Alfa BV\\\hline
        quinoa 270g&   € 0.39& Beta BV\\\hline
        quinoa 360g&   € 0.45& Alfa BV\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont Available grammages for quinoa}
    \label{tab:quinoa grammages example}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
  \hline
    \textbf{Recipe size}&\textbf{Grammage requirement}\\\hline
    2p box&150g\\\hline
    3p box&225g\\\hline
    4p box&300g\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont Quinoa requirement for recipe AB01}
  \label{tab:quinoa usage example}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: you just forgot the `[t]` on the second minipage, unrelated but avoid putting font changes in `\caption` it will mess up the list of tables

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the beginning and end, so we can just copy, compile and see your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks! Now the following question is if there is a way to also align the captions at the bottom independently form the top alignment of the tables (hope the question is clear)

Comment: also @DavidCarlisle thanks for the heads-up about the captions. What is the correct command to make the font smaller?

Comment: @MS-SPO thanks! and done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose this, using the `floatrow` package. However, note this package follows the typographical tradition – namely, caption of tables are *above* the table.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize
    \captionsetup[table]{style=default, font=footnotesize}
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
      \centering
     \ttabbox{ \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       \textbf{SKU}&\textbf{Price}&\textbf{Supplier}\\\hline
            quinoa 90g & € 0.21& Alfa BV\\\hline
            quinoa 180g& € 0.30& Alfa BV\\\hline
            quinoa 270g& € 0.39& Beta BV\\\hline
            quinoa 360g& € 0.45& Alfa BV\\\hline
      \end{tabular}}
     { \caption{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont Available grammages for quinoa}
        \label{tab:quinoa grammages example}}
      \centering
     \ttabbox{ \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
      \hline
        \textbf{Recipe size}&\textbf{Grammage requirement}\\\hline
        2p box&150g\\\hline
        3p box&225g\\\hline
        4p box&300g\\\hline
      \end{tabular}}
     { \caption{\fontsize{9}{11} \selectfont Quinoa requirement for recipe AB01}
      \label{tab:quinoa usage example}}
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This solves all of my issues. many thanks!

Comment: You're  welcome. Always glad when I can help!